# Replace tags with another tag with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, editor

I am making my own small editor using `replace`.

```
function textarea_post(){
    var text = $(".editor").val();
    text = text.replace("<code>","<pre>").replace("</code>","</pre>");
    $(".results").html(text);
}
```

It change textarea `<code></code>` tags to `<pre></pre>`.
The problem is that it only works once.

I tried

```
function textarea_post(){
    var text = $(".editor").val();
    text = text.replace(/<code>/g,"<pre>").replace(/</code>/g,"</pre>");
    $(".results").html(text);
}
```

But it dont work with closing tags.

[image: My editor]

Comment: Escape the slash in the regex ! `.replace(/<\/code>/g,"</pre>");`

Comment: Perfect! Thank you